# .htaccess rewrite on enalog.net

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was googling for long time but nothing works for me. Maybe someone here will give me an answer.

I have web link http://www.enalog.net/index.php?pid=5&menu=domov&page=IZDELAVA-SPLETNIH-STRANI

I want to rewrite it with file .htaccess to page http://www.enalog.net/izdelava-spletne-strani .

I tried samples a lot of tutorials but nothing works for me.

I'll be glad if any one have a solution here.

Thanks in advance.

Cind regards, Ivan

Comment: Is this the only link or do you have other values for `page` ?

Comment: No it's not the only link, I have around 20 links simmilar to this. The only variable which changes is page= ,pid= and menu=

Comment: Then you can't do it with a generic rule (maybe with a RewriteMap) but you'll still have a problem to rewrite `http://www.enalog.net/xxxxxx` to it's pid/page equivalent. You must use a specific rule for each case (or use a map, like i said)

Comment: That's right, You cannot take out `pid=5` from your pretty URL if your internal URL needs that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule /?IZDELAVA-SPLETNIH-STRANI index.php?pid=5&menu=domov&page=IZDELAVA-SPLETNIH-STRANI
```

If it should be a little more flexible try using this:

```
RewriteRule /?([A-Z-]+) index.php?pid=5&menu=domov&page=$1
```

That small regex expects only big letters and minus signes and put them as parameter of your index.php.

If you have a dependency on some IDs put them e.g. in the front and use e.g. another minus sign as delimiter and try this:

```
RewriteRule /?(\d+)-([A-Z-]+) index.php?pid=$1&menu=domov&page=$2
```

Comment: Nope it, doesnt work. My .htaccess file:
"
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule /?(\d+)-(A-Z-) index.php?pid=$1&menu=domov&page=$2
"

Comment: I had a small typo which I already fixed, there where some brackets missing.

Comment: Did you check that mod rewrite is installed and enabled?

Comment: Yes mode rewrite is installed , I have checked thhis.

Comment: Do you have a line like `RewriteEngine on` in your `.htaccess` file? and is `AllowOverride all` set in the directory *tag* in your server configuration?

Comment: Yes I have the line RewriteEngine on and on server is all like it must be.

Comment: Many thanks for help rekire. i will ask my hosting provider to restart server. 
Maybe I also can't rewrite the url because I have variables like pid=5 in the url, which I need in code. 

Thanks again.